# ????? в ответе на запрос через mysqli

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Получая текст с БД в php через конструкцию

```
$SQL = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM `table`");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)){
  echo $row['text'];
}
```

русский текст отображается нормально.

Но используя mуsqli вот так:

```
$SQL = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$SQL->data_seek(0);
while($row = $SQL->fetch_assoc()){
  echo $row['text'];
}
```

Вместо русского текста вижу ??? ??????? ? ??????? ??? ????

Кодировки сайта и БД - UTF8. В чем проблема?

Comment: При подключении нужно кодировку указать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:  нужно указать кодировку подключения. В данном случае:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Comment: пометьте хотяб ответ как верный

Comment: @ScreamingVoices собственный ответ можно пометить не раньше, чем через 48 часов

Comment: по правилам не раньше чем через два дня

Comment: по правилам надо маркировать вопрос как дубль, на который уже есть ответ